# Getting generic arguments for SymbolCallerInfo in Roslyn

Tags: c#, generics, roslyn

I'm attempting to find all locations in a solution that calls the method `IBus.Publish<T>` (from NServiceBus). So far this is working:

```
IMethodSymbol method = ... [IBus.Publish methodsymbol resolved];
var callers = method.FindCallers(solution, new CancellationToken());
```

This results in a `IEnumerable<SymbolCallerInfo>` and I get all the correct references to this method.

How would I now go about to get the generic argument `IBus.Publish` was called with? Do I have to parse the sourcetree manually, or does it exist some Roslyn magic I can leverage?

Example:

In my code I have:

```
IBus _bus;

_bus.Publish<IMyMessage>(msg => { msg.Text = "Hello world"});
```

I'm interested in getting the `IMyMessage` type.

Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: why not use reflection to do that? :)

Comment: @animaonline Because using Reflection to do this stuff when it iterates n solutions, results in a chaos of loading different assemblies, shadow-copying, etc. etc... I've tried. :) Also, Roslyn is the way to go for stuff like this :)

Comment: Okay, is the 'FindCallers' method an actual method? I can't seem to find it

Comment: @animaonline Yeah, it's an extensionmethod on ISymbol. IMethodSymbol in turn inherits ISymbol

Comment: Could you explain why you'd want to find all code which calls Publish? I think what you're building could be very interesting for us as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `SemanticModel` to go from the `SyntaxNode` for the call to the actual `MethodSymbol`, and then you can just read the `TypeArguments` property to get the `TypeSymbol`s for the arguments.  That will even work if the arguments aren't specified explicitly, since the `SemanticModel` will perform type inference.

For example:

```
var callers = method.FindCallers(solution, CancellationToken.None);
foreach (var caller in callers)
{
    foreach (var location in caller.Locations)
    {
        if (location.IsInSource)
        {
            var callerSemanticModel = solution
                .GetDocument(location.SourceTree)
                .GetSemanticModel();
            var node = location.SourceTree.GetRoot()
                .FindToken(location.SourceSpan.Start)
                .Parent;
            var symbolInfo = callerSemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node);
            var calledMethod = symbolInfo.Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
            if (calledMethod != null)
            {
                var arguments = calledMethod.TypeArguments;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, I think you can just look at the TypeArguments of CalledSymbol directly (after casting CalledSymbol to an IMethodSymbol).

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson: That seems to give the unconstructed method, so you get `Publish<T>` for every caller instead of `Publish<IMyMessage>` and `Publish<IYourMessage>`.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the IMethodSymbol and ISymbol interfaces, but here is an another way to get the generic arguments from a `InvocationExpressionSyntax`

```
var methodRef = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)find_method();

var genericArguments = methodRef.DescendantNodes().OfType<GenericNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();

if (genericArguments != null)
   foreach (var g_arg in genericArguments.TypeArgumentList.Arguments)
      Console.WriteLine(g_arg);

static InvocationExpressionSyntax find_method()
{
   var code = new StreamReader("..\\..\\Tests.cs").ReadToEnd();
   SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
   var root = tree.GetRoot();
   //find your methods here
   return (InvocationExpressionSyntax)root.DescendantNodes().ToArray()[88];
}
```

Comment: That's correct, but this is parsing the SyntaxTree, which does not really give me what I want. I need to work with the ISymbol implementations in order for me to find references across different solutions. This will give me a GenericNameSyntax with the name IMyMessage, but it wont tell me which project/namespace it belongs to. So far I haven't been able to figure out if I can get that information from a *Syntax class...

Comment: Yeah I understand, but here's a possible "hack" that you can use 

            var parent = genericArguments.Parent;

            while (!(parent is ClassDeclarationSyntax))
            {
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(parent);

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen If you need to know about projects and namespaces, then you can't use just the syntax tree, you need semantics.